# 2 tables, one with dayofweek and id, the other with date and id mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to mysql so please be gentle.  I have tried to wrap my brain around this task and just don't know where to go.  At this point my brain is mush and I am looking for guidance.

I have 2 tables:  shows and performances.

Shows has showid and is based on a day of the week.  So, a Monday show has dayid 1, Tuesday show has dayid 2, etc.

Performances on the other hand are specific dates the shows happen.  So the showid is included in performances and there is a dateofshow.

What I am trying to do, for example, is list all the monday shows and match with all the performances that have been recorded and indicate which shows have been reported.

So, If I have 3 Monday shows and only 2 performances that correspond to the showid have been reported.  Something like below...

```
+--------+-------+-------+------------+----------+
| showid | dayid | show  | dateofshow | reported |
+--------+-------+-------+------------+----------+
|      1 |     1 | show1 | 9/07/2015  | Yes      |
|      2 |     1 | show2 | NULL       | NO       |
|      3 |     1 | show3 | 9/07/2015  | Yes      |
+--------+-------+-------+------------+----------+
```

mysql...

```
SELECT s.*, pr.*
            FROM shows as s             
            LEFT JOIN performances as pr
            ON s.showid = pr.showid

            WHERE s.dayid = 1
```

Again, thanks for any help.  My brain is fried.

UPDATED: I didn't discuss this earlier but, the dateofshow has to be within the current week.  I have changed the date within the question to better suit the circumstances.  In the above "table" you will notice the shows reported are for 9/7/2015 which is a monday.  All 3 of these shows have performances already reported for 8/31/2015 which is the week prior.  So again, I am looking for dateofshow that is in the current week is "yes" and if dateofshow is only a prior date then "no".  I hope this helps and I do believe we are getting there.  Thanks again for all your help.

I have tried this...

```
SELECT s.showid, s.dayid, s.venueid, v.venue, v.venueid,
   pr.dateofshow, IF(pr.dateofshow = DATE('2015-09-07'), 'Yes', 'No') as reported FROM shows as s JOIN venues as v  ON s.venueid = v.venueid LEFT JOIN performances as pr
     ON s.showid = pr.showid
  WHERE s.dayid = 1
```

It provides me with 'yes' for shows with performances on the set date. and provides 'no' for shows with performances on a date prior to the set date.  Now I need to eliminate those that are earlier then the set date and do if a performance does not exist with the set date then 'no'.

Comment: Looks fine to me, assuming you have dateofshow and reported fields on the performances table?

Comment: I do not have a reported field.  If a show is on Mondays.  And the performance is reported with a date that corresponds to that monday then I want to add the Reported I guess as an alias... (i don't know about this stuff).  So I think I have to determine the date of a monday show and match if the performance dateofshow exists and return Yes, otherwise return null.

Comment: Dates in SQL adhere to a specific format/data type. This does not appear to be it.

Comment: Question includes lot of effort, so motivating to be helped and upvoted, but i must have to wait for some reasonable amount of data.. better to be presented as `insert into shows(...column names..) values(...)` similarly for `performances` table then a sample result from that real data.. You will get answer instantly.... i am not sure sure yet but i hope u are asking one of these two queries...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a68e1/3 .. u can please update my fiddle with data and update your question if your problem not solved there or post an answer if it would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.showid, s.dayid, s.show,
       pr.dateofshow, IF(pr.dateofshow is null,'NO','Yes') as reported
  FROM shows as s             
  LEFT JOIN performances as pr
         ON s.showid = pr.showid
      WHERE s.dayid = 1 
        AND pr.dateofshow > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY)
```

Comment: I will try this in a bit. I can forsee problems with this as there will be performances from previous weeks... so there will be performances with that showid. I will need to only include those from this week. I will need to update the question. And I will try this. It will probably get me closer.

Comment: As I expected this is pulling all showids and performances dateofshow because they all have performances reported.  I will update the question. dateofshow needs to be in the current week.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if i got this rigth but this is what I've don to try to help you out. Here we go.
i would of try a n:n relation on do my statment like that.

```
    SELECT *, 
           CASE 
             WHEN (dateofshow IS NOT null) AND (dateofshow BETWEEN '2015-09-07' AND '2015-09-15' ) 
             THEN 'YES' 
             ELSE 'NO'   
           END
      FROM show 
      JOIN show_performance ON (show.id = show_performance.Idshow)            
      JOIN performance      ON (performance.id = show_performance.idPerformance)
```

created the tables  like that:

```
        CREATE TABLE show(
            id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            name varchar(250) NULL      
         CONSTRAINT [PK_Show] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [id] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]


        CREATE TABLE performance(
            id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            name varchar(250) NULL

         CONSTRAINT [PK_Performanse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [id] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]


        CREATE TABLE show_performance(
            idshow int ,
            idPerformance int ,
            dateofshow  date null   

        )



        ALTER TABLE show_performance WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Performance FOREIGN KEY(idShow)
        REFERENCES [dbo].[show] ([Id])

        ALTER TABLE show_performance WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_show FOREIGN KEY(idPerformance)
        REFERENCES [dbo].[performance] ([Id])
```

so that's my result:

```
           id   name    idshow  idPerformance   dateofshow  id  name    (No column name)
            1   rock    1       2               NULL        2   metalica        NO
            2   pop     2       4               NULL        4   madona          NO
            3   popRock 3       1               NULL        1   iron  maiden    NO
            1   rock    1       1               2015-09-07  1   iron  maiden    YES
            2   pop     2       3               2015-09-30  3   michael jackson NO
            3   popRock 3       4               2015-10-08  4   madona          NO
```